# How can I check for max attributes when I focus on a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 sets of products with quantity field. I need to check that the user should not enter product quantity more that 6. and if user enters more that 6 quantity it should give error in the div below qty field and then reset the qty field to 0 and focus back to the qty field for user to enter quantity again.

This should happen with all 3 sets of products.

Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

```
<!-- first set -->

<div class="sb-table-body">

            <div class="content tableContentRow noTopPad">
                <div>
                    <span class="item_n left transparentBorder"><input type="hidden" name="oid" value="50786361">005209625</span>
                    <span class="description_n left transparentBorder">
                        <a href="$field{site_url_secure}/product/index.html?id=105404446">
                            <strong>LOST or STOLEN IMS iPod and Sled Kit (U.S. and Canada)</strong>
                        </a>
                        <br>
                        <span class="mrfNo">Mfr#: KIT-CAS-520156-S0L9D6</span>
                    </span>
                    <!--<span class="unitPrice_n left textRight adjustRightPad noPadLeft transparentBorder">$<span class="js-unitPrice">545.00</span></span>-->
                    <span class="qty_n left transparentBorder"><span>
                        <span class="js-qty-orig" id="js-qty-orig-50786361">0</span>
                        <input type="text" name="spn_qty_50786361" id="spn_qty_50786361" size="3" value="0"  id='numberbox' maxlength="4" class="js-qty" onkeyup="checkLength(event)">
                    </span></span>
                    <div class="error-message"></div>
                    <!--<span class="extPrice_n left adjustRightPad noPadLeft textRight transparentBorder">$<span class="js-extPrice">0.00</span></span>-->
                </div>
            </div>

<!-- first set end -->


<!-- second set -->         

<div class="content tableContentRow noTopPad">
                <div>
                    <span class="item_n left transparentBorder"><input type="hidden" name="oid" value="50392334">004667652</span>
                    <span class="description_n left transparentBorder">
                        <a href="$field{site_url_secure}/product/index.html?id=104837678">
                            <strong>DEFECTIVE or DAMAGED IMS iPod and Sled Kit (U.S. ONLY)</strong>
                        </a>
                        <br>
                        <span class="mrfNo">Mfr#: KIT-CAS-345278-R3Y2J8</span>
                    </span>
                    <!--<span class="unitPrice_n left textRight adjustRightPad noPadLeft transparentBorder">$<span class="js-unitPrice">30.00</span></span>-->
                    <span class="qty_n left transparentBorder"><span>
                        <span class="js-qty-orig" id="js-qty-orig-50392334">0</span>
                        <input type="text" name="spn_qty_50392334" id="spn_qty_50392334" size="3" value="0" max="6" maxlength="4" class="js-qty" onkeyup="checkLength(event)">
                    </span></span>
                    <!--<span class="extPrice_n left adjustRightPad noPadLeft textRight transparentBorder">$<span class="js-extPrice">0.00</span></span>-->
                </div>
            </div>

<!-- second set ends -->



<!-- third set ends -->
            <div class="content tableContentRow noTopPad">
                <div>
                    <span class="item_n left transparentBorder"><input type="hidden" name="oid" value="50753139">004863908</span>
                    <span class="description_n left transparentBorder">
                        <a href="$field{site_url_secure}/product/index.html?id=105362442">
                            <strong>IMS Heel Cup Charger</strong>
                        </a>
                        <br>
                        <span class="mrfNo">Mfr#: CBL-CUP-LP5PC-BK</span>
                    </span>
                    <!--<span class="unitPrice_n left textRight adjustRightPad noPadLeft transparentBorder">$<span class="js-unitPrice">45.00</span></span>-->
                    <span class="qty_n left transparentBorder"><span>
                        <span class="js-qty-orig" id="js-qty-orig-50753139">0</span>
                        <input type="text" name="spn_qty_50753139" id="spn_qty_50753139" size="3" value="0" max="6" maxlength="4" class="js-qty">
                    </span></span>
                    <!--<span class="extPrice_n left adjustRightPad noPadLeft textRight transparentBorder">$<span class="js-extPrice">0.01</span></span>-->
                </div>
            </div>

<!-- Third set ends -->
```

Comment: Use `input` event...

Comment: onchange event of the text field.

Comment: on event onchange how do I check if max value is more that 6?

Comment: If the user is supposed to write a number in that field, you could change the type to number instead of text

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [onkeyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) event for that purpose.

On the example below, `checkLength()` will print error if the length of the value within the input is less than 6. This function is triggered upon the release of any key.

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="checkLength()">

<script>
function checkLength() {
  const length = document.getElementById("fname").value.length;
  const value = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  if (value < 6 && length > 0) {
    console.log('error!');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it prints error even when I enter 9 or value greater than 6

Comment: @SukhpreetSinghAlang Oh, I initially thought you were referring to the length of the input. So you want the error to show when the value is less than 6, right? I have updated my answer.

Comment: You need to check the length of `fname` `const x = document.getElementById("fname").value.length;`

Comment: @FrancisLeigh Got it! I just realised that too

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('some_id').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
   if(parseInt(this.value,10) <= 6){
      console.log('Fine');
   }else{
      console.log('Max value could be only 6 and not more than that!');
   }
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type='number' id='some_id' />
</body>

</html>
```

You could use [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) event to capture the value and apply validation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const validateMaxLimit = input => {
  const val_length = input.value.length
  const max = input.getAttribute('data-max')

  if (val_length > +max) {
    input.classList.add("error")
  } else {
    input.classList.remove("error")
  }
}

const bindEvents = input => input.addEventListener('keyup', ({target}) => validateMaxLimit(target))


//on load incase predefined values
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
  bindEvents(input)
  validateMaxLimit(input)
})
```

```css
.error {
  border: 2px solid red
}
```

```html
<input type="text" data-max="6" value="1234567">
<input type="text" data-max="7">

<input type="text" data-max="10">
<input type="text" data-max="11" value="123456789111">

<input type="text" data-max="12">
<input type="text" data-max="13">

<input type="text" data-max="14">
<input type="text" data-max="15" value="12345678910">
```